# How to declare overloads function with same parameters, different return type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a function that can be curried(functional programming), I declare it as below:

```
declare function adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T, index: number, list: T[]): T[];
declare function adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T, index: number): (list: T[]) => T[];
declare function adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T): (index: number, list: T[]) => T[];
declare function adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T): (index: number) => (list: T[]) => T[];
```

But in this case, the last line of code will never work because it has same parameters with the penultimate line.

I also consider the `Union Types`, just like:

```
declare function adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T, index: number, list: T[]): T[];
declare function adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T, index: number): (list: T[]) => T[];
declare function adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T): ((index: number, list: T[]) => T[]) | ((index: number) => (list: T[]) => T[]);
```

But it will cause a `ts` mistake:

```
TS2349:Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((index: number, list: number[]) => number[]) | ((index: number) => (list: number[]) => number[])' has no compatible call signatures
```

So, How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a interface with call signature as your return type for the last function:

```
declare interface AdjustReturnFunction<T>{
    (index: number, list: T[]): T[];
    (index: number): (list: T[]) => T[];

}

declare function adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T, index: number, list: T[]): T[];
declare function adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T, index: number): (list: T[]) => T[];
declare function adjust<T>(fn: (a: T) => T): AdjustReturnFunction<T>;
```